# Hide a field and it's label using javascript in html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to hide a field on a page using JavaScript. I've hidden the field successfully by doing this

```
$('[name="EndorsementTypeID"]').hide();
```

However, I am unable to hide the label. This is how the label and the field is defined so not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
<li>
     <label for="EndorsementTypeID">Endorsement Type:&nbsp;</label>
     <b>
       <select id="EndorsementTypeID" name="EndorsementTypeID" aria-label="Endorsement Type"> 
           <option value="-1">[No Endorsement Type]</option>
           <option value="1">TEST</option>
       </select></b>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
$('[name="EndorsementTypeID"]').hide();
```

Selects this element:

```
<select id="EndorsementTypeID" name="EndorsementTypeID" aria-label="Endorsement Type">
```

Based on its `name` attribute.  So to select this element:

```
<label for="EndorsementTypeID">
```

You could also use an attribute:

```
$('[for="EndorsementTypeID"]').hide();
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was missing.